# RSpec - select date cocoon gem

Tags: date, testing, rspec, capybara, apache-cocoon

I am doing some testing regarding my rails app. I am using the gem cocoon regarding some forms. I have some troubles testing the "date selection". I would like to know what I am doing wrong, your help will be much appreciated!!

Please find here below what I have done so far :

Nested fields for Job form ( I am trying to test the input field started_at)

```
    .nested-fields
      = f.input :company_name,  label:'Nom de entreprise', input_html: {class: "form-control job-company-name"}
      = f.input :title, label: 'Votre fonction', input_html: {class: "form-control job-title "}
      = f.input :location, label: 'Lieu de travail', input_html: {class: "form-control job-location"}
      = f.input :started_at, discard_day: true, order: [:month, :year], include_blank: true, label:'Date début',input_html: {class: "work-started-at job-started-at"}, start_year: 1970, end_year: 2016, :id => 'task_target_date'
      = f.input :finished_at, discard_day: true, order: [:month, :year], label: 'Date fin ( mettre le mois en cours si c\'est votre emploi actuel)',input_html: {class: "work-finished-at end_date job-finished-at"},start_year: 1970, end_year: 2016, :default => Time.now   
      = f.input :description, label: 'Vos responsabilités',:input_html => {:rows => 9, style: 'max-width:100%;', class: ""}
   .remove-experience.text-center
      = link_to_remove_association "supprimer cette expérience", f, class: 'btn btn-delete form-button'
```

RSpec and Capybara

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Edit Profile" do

  scenario "Profile updated successfully ", js: true do 
    Given "user visits profile edit page"
    When "user updates profile basic info"
    When "user updates work experiences info"
    When "user updates education info"
    Then "user views profile updated"
  end



  def user_updates_work_experiences_info
    click_link "Parcours professionnel"
    click_link "Ajouter une expérience"
    find(".job-company-name").set("Natixis")
    find(".job-title").set("Contrôleur Financier")
    find(".job-location").set("Paris")
    select_date("2013,December,7", :from => "Date début")
  end


  def select_date(date, options = {})
    field = options[:from]
    base_id = find(:xpath, ".//label[contains(.,'#{field}')]")[:for]
    year, month, day = date.split(',')
    select year,  :from => "#{base_id}_1i"
    select month, :from => "#{base_id}_2i"
  end


end
```

When I run the test, I have the following message :

```
Failure/Error: select year,  :from => "#{base_id}_1i"
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find select box "profile_experiences_attributes_1467917726232_started_at_2i_1i"
```

Thank you guys ;)

Comment: I'm guessing your label doesn't contain the text "job-started-at", please add the actual generated HTML rather than the erb so we can confirm that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is finally working. I first checked the rails console to view what was the value of the variable `base`:

```
profile_experiences_attributes_1467922079698_started_at_2i
```

I have removed the last 3 characters of the variable with the following code :

```
base_id = base[0...-3]
```

And updated the select_date method :

```
 def select_date(date, options = {})
    field = options[:from]
    base = find(:xpath, ".//label[contains(.,'#{field}')]")[:for]
    base_id = base[0...-3]
    year, month, day = date.split(',')
    select month, :from => "#{base_id}_2i"
    select year,  :from => "#{base_id}_1i"
  end
```

Green light everywhere!!! Much appreciated your assistance Tom

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your erb, I believe your label would actually contain the text 'Date début' and not 'job-started-at' (need the actual generated HTML to confirm that).  Because of that, with your select_date method the way it is currently you would need to call

```
select_date("2013,December,7", :from => 'Date début')
```

Another option would be to change the selector/expression in the `find` call in select_date.  Either way I believe you're going to run into another issue since you're specifying `discard_day: true` which I assume means there will be no day field to select from so `select day,   :from => "#{base_id}_3i"` will error.  You're going to need to update your `select_date` method to make it more flexible.

Comment: Thank you Tom Walpole for your assitance. It is definitely related to the label. When I change the label like you did in your answer I have the following error :  Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find select box "profile_experiences_attributes_1467917726232_started_at_2i_1i"  I will updpate my question with the erb

Comment: @purplecode So it's building the selector incorrectly - notice the _2i_1i  -- that should only be _1i  -  You need to look at the actual HTML (as I mentioned) and figure out what exactly you're getting on your page and then rewrite your select_date method to work properly

Comment: Ok I going to take a look right now and give you an update. Thanks for your quick answer

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom Walpole it is now working, you lead me to the correct methdo. I have changed the select_date method with the following code

Comment: def select_date(date, options = {})
    field = options[:from]
    base = find(:xpath, ".//label[contains(.,'#{field}')]")[:for]
    base_id = base[0...-3]
    year, month, day = date.split(',')
    select month, :from => "#{base_id}_2i"
    select year,  :from => "#{base_id}_1i"
  end